# Numpy array - Getting the index only if the adjacent values not duplicates - python

Tags: python, numpy, duplicates

I have an array as below.

```py
arr = np.array(['horse', 'horse', 'horse', 'deer', 'deer', 'horse', 'cat', 'deer'])
```

Need the indexes only if the adjacent values in the array is not duplicated using python.
That is, the expected output is `[0,3,5,6,7]`. Please help to get this result without for-loop.

Answer (score 3):

It's a little bit more involved with `strings` inside an `np.array`

```py
import numpy as np

arr = np.array(['horse', 'horse', 'horse', 'deer', 'deer', 'horse', 'cat', 'deer'])

factors, indices = np.unique(arr, return_inverse=True)
np.flatnonzero(np.r_[1,np.diff(indices)])
```

Out:

```
array([0, 3, 5, 6, 7])
```

Answer (score 2):

It doesn't give you the exact answer directly, but I think it is easier to understand. You can compare each value to the one before it to see whether they are equal.

```
import numpy as np

arr = np.array(['horse', 'horse', 'horse', 'deer', 'deer', 'horse', 'cat', 'deer'])

print( arr[1:] )
# ['horse' 'horse' 'deer' 'deer' 'horse' 'cat' 'deer']
print( arr[:-1] )
# ['horse' 'horse' 'horse' 'deer' 'deer' 'horse' 'cat']
print( arr[1:] != arr[:-1] )
# [False False  True False  True  True  True]
```

and you can get the indexes by using `nonzero()`.

```
out = (arr[1:] != arr[:-1]).nonzero()[0] + 1
print( out )
# [3 5 6 7]
```

To get the exact answer, you can insert the `0` to the start as it is always going to be there.

```
answer = np.insert(out,0,0)
print( answer )
# [0 3 5 6 7]
```